# Conditional probability involving poker cards

Tags: probability

In poker game card, $ 52 $ cards are distributed equally among $ 4 $ players $ A, B, C, $ and $ D. $ If $ A $ and $ B $ have a total of $ 8 $ spades, what is the probability that $ C $ has $ 3 $ of the remaining $ 5 $ spades?

My approach is to consider the reduced sample space involving $ C $'s and $ D $'s cards, that is, there remains $ 26 $ cards to be distributed to $ C $ and $ D $ and so the probability that $ C $ has $ 3 $ of the remaining $ 5 $ spades is $ \displaystyle \frac{\binom{5}{3}\binom{21}{10}}{\binom{26}{13}} \approx 0.339. $

However, I am attempting the second approach using the conditional probability formula $ \displaystyle P(E|F) = \frac{P(EF)}{P(F)} $ where $ F $ is the probability that $ A $ and $ B $ have a total of $ 8 $ spades and $ E $ is the probability that $ C $ has $ 3 $ of the remaining $ 5 $ spades. I calculate $ \displaystyle P(F) = \frac{\binom{13}{8}}{\binom{52}{26}} $ but still get stuck on $ P(EF) $ so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first looks good. In the second approach, $\Pr(F)$ is already not right, we need  $\binom{13}{8}\binom{39}{18}$ on top. And the game looks like bridge, not poker.

Answer (score 1):

$P(A|B) = P(B|A) \frac {P(B)}{P(A)}$

A = 3 spades in C

B = 8 spades in hands A and B.

$P(B | A) = $ the probability that 8 spades, and 18 not spades go to A and B given that 3 spades and 10 non spades have gone to C.  It also equals the chance that 2 spades go to D.

$P(B | A)  = \frac {{10\choose8}{29\choose 18}}{39 \choose 26}= P(\text {2 spades in D} | A) = \frac {{10\choose2}{29\choose 11}}{39 \choose 13}$

$P(B) = \frac {{13\choose 3}{39\choose 10}}{52\choose 13}\\
P(A) =  \frac {{13\choose 8}{39\choose 18}}{52\choose 26}$

Comment: An explanation for *why* you say that is needed.  It appears you are using the same logic that GrahamKemp is below, but as mentioned in comments there, the end locations of the spades are not independent of one another.

Comment: @JMoravits I have updated my answer.  My first answer had a simplification, that in hindsight I cannot justify.  Is this more to your satisfaction?

Answer (score 0):

*Another way*

Forget about cards other than spades, and reduce the problem to distributing $5$ spades to $C$ and $D$ each having $13$ slots, so that $C$ gets $3$ and $D$ gets $2$

$Pr = \frac{\binom{13}{3}\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{26}{5}} \approx 0.339$